# How can I set a default value to a input when opening it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input component, and I want to set the default value when I open it (like set the `display` property `block`), and then I can control the input.
[code example](https://jsfiddle.net/qgzysm5p/6/)

I tried to use `componentWillReceiveProps` or the new lifecycle `getDerivedStateFromProps`. But I found some articles saying that this is antipattern.

Is there a better way to accomplish my goals?

Comment: You may want to check out [React Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) .

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, could you edit your question and try to make it clearer, you can set `defaultProps` for a component and it will be overridden if user specifies that prop when instantiating the component, is that what you want ?

Comment: I'm not really sure you want default styling or want to set a default value

Comment: Your code has no problem.

Comment: em。Maybe the question is not clear。The focus of the problem isn't style，I use a `controled component`,So its value is based on `state`,but I want to change the default value based on the `props`.

Answer (score 0):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is a good choice, add code below to your InputForm:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, state){
    if(nextProps.show && !state.show) {
        return {
          show: true,
          value: 'default value'
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dkhz32x9/

Comment: I always do this.But I found  some articles saying that this is not good or `Anti-pattern`

Comment: using it you have 1 anti-pattern, but not using it will produce two or more. Base on your feel, others do not live your life ._.